# rsyslog can't compile regex pattern within template

Tags: regex, logging, rsyslog

I have the below rsyslog config which reads a non-standard formatted log file and parses the data I need into json payload. Now, when I'm trying to extract everything behind the last set of brackets which can contain `[Info  ]` or `[Error ]` it throws an error saying: error compiling regex. I know the regex pattern `(?:\[Info\s*\]|\[Error\s*\])\s*(.*)` should work (tested on the regex checker on rsyslog's website, as well as on other checkers) but I don't quite understand to why rsyslog can't compile it. If I don't escape brackets, it's throwing a bunch of other errors. Am I missing something obvious?

**/path/to/log/file.log**

```
 11955 - [Mon Apr  6 20:40:03 2023] [Info   ] This message can contain anything [d54d13fa-4657-4891-f99d08674ee]
```

**/etc/rsyslog.d/mylog.conf**

```
module(load="imfile")
input(type="imfile" tag="mylog" file="/path/to/log/file.log")
    
template(name="jsonFormat" type="list" option.jsonf="on") {                 
    property(outname="msg" name="msg" regex.expression="(?:\\[Info\\s*\\]|\\[Error\\s*\\])\\s*(.*)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1" format="jsonf")
}

if ($syslogtag == "mylog") then {
        action(type="omfile" file="/path/to/output/file.log" template="jsonFormat")
}
```

**# rsyslogd -N1**

```
rsyslogd: error compiling regex '(?:\[Info\s*\]|\[Error\s*\])\s*(.*)' [v8.2302.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex ERE syntax does not include the non-capture syntax `(?:)`. Perhaps the regex checker is for a newer version of rsyslog.
You can simply change the `regex.submatch` to 2:

```
regex.expression="(\\[Info\\s*\\]|\\[Error\\s*\\])\\s*(.*)"
regex.submatch="2"
```

Comment: I couldn't find any info on that but that's really good to know! That did the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any documentation to the syntax? I'm even struggling with an easy regex as this `\\[(.*?)\\]` ..

Comment: I dont know of an rsyslog document on the patterns it accepts, but there's
a summary of [POSIX ERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions),
and the actual [reference
doc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).
A lot of other code uses Perl's regex syntax, such as `(?:)`, and known as PCRE. If you have
perl installed, try `perldoc perlre`, or [online](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That reference doc was actually helpful!